# Ubuntu 20.04.3 "Authentication required" loop on 2.4GHz network

Tags: networking, wireless

I am fairly new to the world of Ubuntu and I am having the following problem:
When connecting to a 2.4GHz network I am unable to connect and am stuck on an "Authentication required" loop that asks me to enter a password for the wireless network. I am 100% certain it is the correct password. A suggestion to use the "WPS" button also failed. However, the same router also has a 5GHz network available and I am able to successfully connect to that 5GHz network. Sadly, as it is a 5GHz network, its reach is not sufficient and I would be much better off using the 2.4GHz network, that... I am unable to connect to. Also, I am able to connect to a hot spot created on a mobile device. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Edit 1:
The window says, I quote:

> Authentication required

> Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network "[Network name]"

Edit 2:
I pulled out an old USB Wireless Network Card, it was capable of connecting to the 2.4GHz network. While that technically solves the issue, I consider this a bandaid. I would still like to solve the issue with the main built-in network card

Comment: Is the "authentication required" for superuser privileges or is it asking for the WiFi password?

Comment: It says: "Authentication required

Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network "[Network name]"" @Nmath

Comment: Doesn't sound familiar. Can you upload a screenshot?  Have you tried removing the network and adding it again?  Have you tried using your Ubuntu user's password?  Have you checked router firmware settings?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well but I managed to solve it by luck i guess.
I found [this](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-find-saved-wireless-wifi-passwords-ubuntu/) thread which included the command `sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<WiFi_Network_Name>.nmconnection` to display connection settings for a specific wifi. I compared my 2.4Ghz (which worked) and 5Ghz (which did not) and found one deviation which was the line `auth-alg=open` under the `[wifi-security]` section. It was missing in the 5Ghz config.

I added the line in the 5Ghz config and restarted network manager with `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` and after that everything worked as expected.

Comment: Hello. I added this line "auth-alg=open" to the corresponding file, but I can't restarted network manager. I am using Ubuntu 23.04 and I don't have "network-manager" in "init.d", only the following ones appear: alsa-utils,grub-common,saned,anacron,hwclock.sh,speech-dispatcher,apparmor,irqbalance,spice-vdagent,apport,kerneloops,sssd,avahi-daemon,keyboard-setup.sh,udev,bluetooth,kmod,ufw,console-setup.sh,openvpn,unattended-upgrades,cron,plymouth,uuidd,cups,plymouth-log,whoopsie,dbus,procps,x11-common,gdm3,rsync. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

for those in Ubuntu 23.04, you can restart "network-manager" on the command line with this:

`sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Sorry, I can't reply to @user140259.